How to Send Form Data to Webhook Only After Successful Stripe Payment?
I have a form on my website with multiple fields, including a "Select your Product" dropdown. Depending on the selected product, users are redirected to a corresponding Stripe checkout link after submitting the form. This redirection is working fine.
The form also collects additional information such as Full Name, Height, Weight, Days of sport per week, Type of work, etc.
I need the following functionality:

User completes the form.
User is redirected to Stripe for payment.
After a successful payment, I receive a webhook notification containing both the Stripe payment information and the data from the form.

The requirement is that the form data should only be sent to the webhook if the customer completes the payment on Stripe. If the user fills out the form but does not pay, I do not want to receive any data.
How can I achieve this? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You would leverage metadata for your form data here. The general way to do this would be utilizing a Stripe Checkout Session and then listening for the checkout.session.completed Webhook Event (see info on fulfillment here) which will contain the metadata that you passed through on Checkout Session creation.
